# Rest API, where to put heavy computation in routes?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am intending to design a Rest API, which receives user request and do heavy computation and return the result.

I am new to web programming. so just get familiar with basic API service.

what I know:

1) request sent by post method with JSON, because data is not so simple.
2) I followed some examples and been successful with basics.

so I think I better start writing the heavy computation part.

I want it as following.

1) receive post request, and start to compute

2) just after computing send "working msg" (I think I can just do re.send("MSG"))

my questions

1)but where should I put my heavy computing?

2)since I already responded with "MSG", how can I send another content when there is no request?

3) I have read about middleware, and feels like middleware handles things between receiving request and sending response. am I right?

It would be great if you could show me a simple examples.

Comment: REST is all about "resources" and what you're doing to them, it might help get better answers if you provided some context as to what the computation you're doing is. As a starting point though, HTTP 202 (Accepted) is a useful status code if you're just taking some input to process, but don't want to guarantee anything is going to work yet.

Comment: Do it in background as this.lau said. Node.js is ONE THREAD ONLY, therefore if you do heavy processing in it, it blocks all the incoming messages.

Comment: @TomDavies thx, I will look for how to do background jobs now

Comment: @libik can you show me any example code of something like this?

Comment: @alim - example of what? If yuo google "node.js single thread" you find a lot information about it.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the best way to implement this is to do the heavy processing server-side in the background, and provide a way for the client to check if the job is completed or not.

For example, let's say you want to run some heavy calculation. You could create a resource like this:

```
POST /calculator
```

The client POST a calculation, then the resource queue the calculation job for later processing (maybe by some cron job on the server) and respond with a job resource:

```
{ "id": 123456, "status": "pending" }
```

Then the clients can check at any time if the job is completed by checking the /jobs resource:

```
GET /jobs/123456
```

which initially might respond with this again:

```
{ "id": 123456, "status": "pending" }
```

Then when it's in progress:

```
{ "id": 123456, "status": "in_progress" }
```

And when it's done:

```
{ "id": 123456, "status": "done", "result": <some object that contains the result of the calculation> }
```